# How to disabled javascript when mouse out div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to disabled javascript when mouse out div ?

This is my code `onmousemove` to change div id `left` width, but why javascript still work, when i `onmouseout` id `container` how to disabled javascript when i `onmouseout` out id `container`

i tried

```
    container.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });
```

but not work , how can i do that ?

https://jsfiddle.net/ksfqgv0p/2/

```
var isResizing = false;
$(function () {
   var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');

    container.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
    });

    container.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
        return;
        left.css('width', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
        handle.css('margin-left', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
    });
});
```

Comment: Check my answer. If this is not what you meant then add a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var isResizing = false;
$(function () {
   var container = $('#container'),
        left = $('#left'),
        handle = $('#handle');

    left.on('mousemove', function (e) {
        isResizing = true;
    });

    left.on('mouseout', function (e) {
        isResizing = false;
    });

    $(document).on('mousemove', function (e) {
        if (!isResizing) 
        return;
        left.css('width', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
        handle.css('margin-left', e.clientX - container.offset().left);
    });
});
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ksfqgv0p/4/)

Comment: a problem with an implementation like this is that if you move your mouse too fast then it will outpace the movement of the bar, and will "mouseout". But you should expect that when you want a hover JS event.